# java cassandra object mapping annotations

Tags: java, dictionary, cassandra, cql3, datastax-java-driver

Can you provide an example for mapping collections using datastax api annotations to use Map.

```
class pojo {

  @PartitionKey(value = 0)
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  String userId;

  @Column(name = "attributes")
      // How to map it
      Map<String, String> attributes;
    }
```

error log :

```
2015-08-03 16:33:34,568 INFO  com.jpma.jpmc.slot.persistance.DAOFactory main - Cassandra Cluster Details: ConnectionCfg [userName=test, password=test, port=9042, seeds=[Ljava.lang.String;@1a85bd75, keySpace=test]
java.lang.Class
2015-08-03 16:33:34,646 DEBUG com.datastax.driver.mapping.EntityMapper main - Preparing query INSERT INTO "test"."user_event_date"("user_id","entry_date","entry_time","app","attributes","user_ip","user_authschemes") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown identifier attributes
```

Comment: Can you share your 'create table' cql?    This is likely just complaining that there is no 'attributes' column.  The driver will create prepared statements for each query that would be made as result of your declared model and it looks like the server is rejecting this one.

Comment: yep you are right issue resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message you are seeing, I'm guessing that `attributes` is not defined in your table definition.  Would you mind editing your post with that?

But when I build my CQL table like this (note the compound partition key of `itemid` and `version`):

```
CREATE TABLE products.itemmaster (
    itemid text,
    version int,
    productid uuid,
    supplierskumap map<uuid, text>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((itemid,version), productid)
);
```

...insert this row:

```
INSERT INTO products.itemmaster (itemid,version,productid,supplierskumap) 
VALUES ('item1',1,26893749-dcfc-42c7-892c-bee8c9cff630,
        {1351f82f-5dc5-4328-82f4-962429c92a2b:'86CCG123'});
```

...and I build my POJO like this:

```
@Table(keyspace = "products", name = "itemmaster")
public class Product {
    @PartitionKey(0)
    private String itemid;
    @PartitionKey(1)
    private int version;
    @ClusteringColumn
    private UUID productid;
    @Column(name="supplierskumap")
    private Map<UUID,String> suppliersku;

    public UUID getProductid() {
        return productid;
    }
    public void setProductid(UUID _productid) {
        this.productid = _productid;
    }
    public int getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }
    public void setVersion(int _version)
    {
        this.version = _version;
    }
    public String getItemid() {
        return itemid;
    }
    public void setItemid(String _itemid) {
        this.itemid = _itemid;
    }
    public Map<UUID, String> getSuppliersku() {
        return suppliersku;
    }
    public void setSuppliersku(Map<UUID, String> _suppliersku) {
        this.suppliersku = _suppliersku;
    }
}
```

...with this constructor and `getProd` method on my data access object (dao):

```
public ProductsDAO()
{
    session = connect(CASSANDRA_NODES, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    prodMapper = new MappingManager(session).mapper(Product.class);
}

public Product getProd(String itemid, int version, UUID productid) {
    return prodMapper.get(itemid,version,sku);
}
```

...then this `main` class successfully queries my table and maps my `Map`:

```
private static void main(String[] args) {
        ProductsDAO dao = new ProductsDAO();
        Product prod = dao.getProd("item1", 1, UUID.fromString("26893749-dcfc-42c7-892c-bee8c9cff630"));

        System.out.println(
                prod.getProductid() + " - " + 
                prod.getItemid() + " - " + 
                prod.getSuppliersku().get(UUID.fromString("1351f82f-5dc5-4328-82f4-962429c92a2b")));

        dao.closeCassandra();
}
```

...and produces this output:

```
26893749-dcfc-42c7-892c-bee8c9cff630 - item1 - 86CCG123
```

NOTE: *Edit made to the above example to support a compound partition key.*

Comment: Yep I got the issue, can you share an example to get the object when I have a compound partion key @PartitionKey(0)
 @Column(name="user_id")
 String userId;
 
 @PartitionKey(1)
 @Column(name="attribute_key")
 String attributeKey;

Comment: @PavanKumar Edit made.  Hope this helps!